# how to do json parser in android using json structure

Tags: json

[image]

I have json structure like as shown in image. How should I use jsonparser for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
String data;//your entire JSON data as String


        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
            String status = object.getString("status");
            String response = object.getString("response");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **Model class** like your JSON
and use [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse your json into model.